# Confusion regarding pdfs and likelihood

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayes-theorem

[image]

I am finding the question above really confusing, sketching the pdfs is fine, but I don't understand how the pdfs give us the likelihoods ie p(x|A) and p(x|B). From what I have understood the p(x) values are not probabilities, rather the areas between points on the pdf give use the probabilities.

Later in this question it asks for the probability that given a tree is 6m tall, what is the probability that it is a type A tree?

So this is asking for p(A|x), so we can use bayes theorm to get this with a p(x|A), p(A) and p(x)....

In the solution, they simply sub in the equation of the pdf ie 10-x/50 for p(x|A) into bayes theorm, and this contradicts my understanding that the pdf itself does not output probabilities, which the solution implies when using it in bayes theorm, as our p(x|A).

Comment: Don't overcomplicate it. $p(X|A)$ is just the probability that a tree of type $A$ has height $x$. More precisely, it should be the pdf. So just sketch a linear function that goes from $2$ to $0$ (for $x$ from $0$ to $10$). In the Bayes theorem, you can input densities instead of probabilities, it's ok. If this confuses you, replace the $6m$ by "we assume that the trees has height between $5.999$ and $6.0001m$, check yourself that there is no difference. Just both numerator and denominator would be multiplied by a small $\epsilon$.

Comment: so say the pdf is (10-x)/50, plugging x=6 into this function would give me p(x=6|A)?

Comment: I would say, yes. Formally, you shouldn't call it probability but rather density. But I would say this is probably what they mean (quoting "sketch the pdf, **i.e.** p(...)").

Comment: So in theory the p(x|A) can be >1 in this case as our probability density can be greater than 1?

Comment: Look, probability can be not greater than 1. Density can be. My understanding is, they are just mixing it up (sketch the pdfs of the heights of type $A$...), just ignore the $p(X|A)$ if it bothers you. In the second part (Bayes), yes, just work with densities.

Comment: So bayes theorm can take a density in replace for the p(X|A), and this density obviously can be greater than 1. Okay I think i've got it somewhat. Thank you for your help, really appreciate it.